# Re-use a java socket client once again

Tags: java, sockets

My  question is very simple. I just want to use a client object socket once again.

Typically people create a new socket any time the client tries to connect the server such:

```
 Socket test = new Socket (host, port);
 OutputStream out = test.getOutputStream ();
 InputStream in = test.getInputStream ();
 out.writeObject (object)
 out.flush ();
 in.readObject();
```

After the first writeObject I do want again to send more information to the server by reusing out.writeObject(nextObject) however the server is no longer reached. In order to get it working I have to go through all the steps above. Why?

---

Here is the code I am using to test what I meant. The code after "Second Request doesn't ..." does not reach the server. However if I remove the comments just above those comments it will go through. Why cannot I re-use the same client socket object without having to use new Socket ().

```
Class Hello -> Data passed between the server and the client
Class TestClient -> Client
Class TestServer -> Server


package tests;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Hello implements Serializable {

    String hola = "hello my friend";

    public String getHello () {

        return hola;

    }

    public void setHello (String str) {

        hola = str;

    }

}


package tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        try {

            ObjectOutputStream clientOutput;
            ObjectInputStream serverInput;
            Hello goingout = new Hello ();

            Socket client = new Socket ("localhost", 5555);
            clientOutput  = new ObjectOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
            serverInput   = new ObjectInputStream (client.getInputStream());

            clientOutput.writeObject(goingout);
            clientOutput.flush();
            Hello comingin = (Hello) serverInput.readObject();
            System.out.println ("first time received: " + comingin.getHello());


            /*
             * Socket client = new Socket ("localhost", 5555);
               clientOutput  = new ObjectOutputStream (client.getOutputStream());
               serverInput   = new ObjectInputStream (client.getInputStream());
             */

            /*
             * Second request doesn't got through the server
             */
            comingin.setHello("again");
            clientOutput.writeObject(goingout);
            clientOutput.flush();
            comingin = (Hello) serverInput.readObject();
            System.out.println ("second time received: " + comingin.getHello());



        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println (ex.getMessage());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println (ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println (ex.getMessage());
        }


    }

}

public class TestServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        try {

              ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555, 100);
              ObjectInputStream clientInput;
              ObjectOutputStream serverOutput;

              for (;;) {
                  System.out.println ("Listening for connections");
                  Socket fromClient = server.accept();
                  serverOutput = new ObjectOutputStream (fromClient.getOutputStream());
                  clientInput = new ObjectInputStream (fromClient.getInputStream());
                  Hello received = (Hello) clientInput.readObject();
                  serverOutput.writeObject(received);
                  serverOutput.flush();
              }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe the server is closing the connection?  Can you show us the server code?

Comment: Maybe the server is not understanding the information sent and closing the socket.  What is contained in the server logs?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the declaration of `Socket fromClient = server.accept();` on the server is inside the scope of the `for` loop. So at the end of the `for` loop (after `serverOutput.flush();`) the `fromClient` variable is destroyed and a new one is created the next time the loop begins. You will need to restructure it like this if you want the same connection to be able to send/receive multiple messages:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashMap

public class User extends Runnable
{
    public String username;
    public Socket socket;
    public TestServer testServerReference;
    ObjectInputStream clientInput;
    ObjectOutputStream serverOutput;

    public User(Socket s, TestServer tS)
    {
        socket = s;
        testServerReference = tS;
    }

    /**
     *  Creates the in/out Streams, returns the username
     */
    public String init()
    {
        serverOutput = new ObjectOutputStream (fromClient.getOutputStream());
        clientInput = new ObjectInputStream (fromClient.getInputStream());
        this.username = (String)clientInput.readObject();  //the first thing the client should send is a username

    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //add send/receive logic here for connected client
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            testServerReference.removeUser(username);
        }
    }
}

public class TestServer {

    public static HashMap<String,User> userList = new HashMap<String,User>();
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try {

              ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5555, 100);

              while (true) //start accepting new connections
              {
                  System.out.println ("Listening for connections");
                  Socket fromClient = server.accept();
                  User newUser = new User(fromClient,this);
                  String newUsername = newUser.init();
                  userList.add(newUsername,newUser);
                  (new Thread(newUser)).start();
              }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void removeUser(String username)
    {
        userList.remove(username);
    }

}
```

I just threw this code together really quickly and have not yet test compiled it, so it may still contain a couple errors, but the general idea is there.

Comment: Hi aioi222, Thanks for the answer but that is not what I am looking for. The server.accept must be in the loop to pile them up when many client requests are sent to the same server at the same time. The problem here is that means that "new ObjectInputStream" must be done within the loop, which means the client at the other side does not know that its Outputstream is now lose, sending the message to no-one.

Comment: hmm just realized the problems comes from the fact that the socket is re-written hence from the client perspective, the other end is not responding any more. Shall find out the solution and post it back here

Comment: There are a number of solutions to this. Each time that a new user connects you will need to save off that socket and the associated streams to a List. You could then spawn a new listener thread for each connection that handles sending/receiving messages for the associated socket. Another option is to have a single thread that listens for new connections and a single thread that iterates through all the connections and checks them for new input and sends new output to them. A third option would be to set timeouts on the sockets and socket acceptor and do it all from a single thread.

Comment: The server I have got in reality create a threads per different client and then that client is talking always to that thread in a different socket than what it did at first instance. So that problem is sorted. The one that is not sorted is when that client sends as well multiple-requests. YOu need to get the accept in the loop to queue them up as the server cannot serve them all at the same time. Another problem would be analyzing the data first, check what user is and then read from the list the corresponding socket. This is over-engineering, I believe.

Comment: I've edited my original answer with some example code that I think matches your problem a little better. It is loosely based on the code you posted below.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see your solution. I will have a look at it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

### You need to use a threaded server.

It is possible for a server to attend multiple clients.  Each server socket must be handled by its own thread.  The server listens on a known socket and each client connects using a separate socket (so multiple clients can run on the same host).

First off, the JavaDocs are one of the worst places to go to understand *how or why* you should use a library, they really only tell you *what* the library does.

Your post that it isn't possible is true only if you stay with a [single threaded server](http://darksleep.com/player/SocketExample/).

Oracle has a page on [Java server sockets](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html) that explains multiple clients (with reuse) with a single server.

They also have an [advanced sockets page](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/sockets/) that goes into more detail.

Comment: Hi Kelly French. Thanks. My server is already multi-threaded. A client always talk to a separate thread for ever until one of the two decide to halt the conversation. The only way of doing that is to pass the overwritten socket context to the original socket (the first connection of the thread with the client). I will have to do such thing.

Comment: If you share one socket between multiple threads, it is no longer multi-threaded in the way we mean. Yes it may still have multiple threads but the shared socket causes contention typical to threaded programs, such as the issue in your question where one thread is closing a socket shared by a second thread.  A multi-threaded server usually indicates that each thread has its own socket connection and does not share.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept%28%29.

It simply cannot be done when you have a server attending multiple clients. Server.accept creates a new socket so that means that the client loses the connection with the socket that the server created at first instance, as this overwrite the socket object.

You cannot get the accept out of the loop because that means the server would listen to only one client. You may be able to play with two instances but this solution would be only available for a server listening to multiple requests of one client only.

In summary, it cannot be done hence all the example on the net uses new Socket() at the client side any time it is trying to send new information to the server, even if the client is the same.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is possible to have multiple clients connected and sending/receiving messages without the need to recreate the socket each time. I would recommend getting on google and searching for a simple Java based chat client/server.

Comment: This is different. There is not server.accept which create a new socket. readLIne flows the information over the same socket all the time. It has nothing to do.

Comment: sorry just kicked the keyboard :). In order to find a solution I have to be able to pass the context of the over-written socket to the socket that is contact with the client. At this stage I have to evaluate if such solution is better than just overwriting them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok people. Thanks to aoi222 and Kely French mainly, but thanks to anyone else. I found the solution which is:

1.- Obviously you need to create a thread that serves a client exclusively. First time the client connects to the server to a general port. This create a thread listening to a particular port and let the client know which the new port, the new thread will be listening to. Then the client change its port and create a new socket to start the conversation with the client.

2.- The server, running as a separate thread, must keep listening to a loop as aoi222 indicated for ever. The accept is just out of the loop for the exclusive thread which has been assigned a client. Please see the code below and sorry for the name of the variables as they are a bit confusing:

```
      fromClient = server.accept();
      clientInput = new ObjectInputStream (fromClient.getInputStream());
      serverOutput = new ObjectOutputStream (fromClient.getOutputStream());
      Hello received;

      while ( (received = (Hello)clientInput.readObject()) != null ) {
          received.setHello("pepito grillo");
          serverOutput.writeObject(received);
      }
```

3.- Please see that the main thread server DO need to have the server.accept within the loop in order to accept new clients connection

```
       for (;;) {
              newClient = mainServer.accept();
              new exclusiveThread ().start ()
       }
```

"exclusiveThread" is a thread that implements the code in 2.

**Edited:**
I forgot to say that the client must send a end message for the server to identify that the conversation has finished and stop the lopp. Otherwise it will result in a java.io.EOFException.

Thanks guys a lot for your help.